# Multiple FirebaseAuth instances: which one is used for queries?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

using the Android Firebase SDKs I can define multiple FirebaseAuth instances associated with a Firebase app as shown below.

My question is: which auth instance will be used to perform Firebase db queries? Is is always the one that last signed in? How can I control which instance will be used?

Thanks!

```
String uri = "http://firebasedb...";
FirebaseApp app = ...

FirebaseAuth auth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app);
auth1.signInWithCustomToken(customToken1);

FirebaseAuth auth2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app);
auth2.signInWithCustomToken(customToken2);

DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app, uri).getReference();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app)` will return you the same instance no matter how many times it will be invoked, and it will be the instance that will be used to signed in most recently.

Thus, `auth1` and `auth2` will be referring to same instance, which will be onward used to query database.